# Netlogo: Choosing an agent to run a procedure from variable values

Tags: variables, comparison, procedure, netlogo, agent

I am creating a taxi-like simulation in which vehicles search for customers. When a vehicle is within 1 unit distance of the customer, it picks up the customer and takes it to its destination (and begins searching for customers again, etc.).

My issue: if 2 vehicles come within 1 unit distance of the same customer within the same time-step, I need the vehicle with the highest [rating] (vehicles-own variable) to always get the customer. This is my code (updated from a previous post):

```
    to find-customers
         if (distance closest-customer <= 1)
         [ask closest-customer [check-for-vehicles]]
    end  

    to check-for-vehicles
         set competitors vehicles in-radius 1
         determine-highest-rated
    end  

    to determine-highest-rated
         set highest-rated max-one-of competitors [rating]
         ask highest-rated [set color red] 
    end
```

[competitors] and [highest-rated] are waiting-customer-own variables. closest-customer is min-one of waiting-customers (distance myself). Normally [set color red] would run the procedure in which the vehicle gets the customer transport information. When forcing two vehicles on the same customer, the correct vehicle always sets its color red. Sometimes the incorrect vehicle also sets its color red. When I check the variable values for the waiting-customer, the correct vehicle is identified as highest-rated, yet sometimes the other vehicle still turns red. There is obviously a mistake with how I've set up the procedures. If anyone has suggestions on how to fix this (or how to approach this task differently) it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why your `ifelse` always return false is because the `ifelse` is placed at the same time step as the initialization of `identification`for each taxi.

The way netlogo works when running some function to an agenset is, each agent, one by one will individually run the function in random order, not in the same time.

So, if the `ifelse` is placed just right after the `identification` is set and in the same function, it will always return false since the other vehicles haven't got their identification set yet. Then it will directly run `make-deal` before even compare it to other-vehicles.

for example:

```
ask vehicle [
   set identification ...
   ifelse ... [..]
   [..]
]
```

is different with

```
ask vehicle [set identification ...]
ask vehicle [ifelse .... [...][...] ]
```

The first one will make each agent set their identification and do the ifelse statement before make other agent do.
The second one will make every agent set their identification first then make every agent do the ifelse statement.

The conclusion is, I suggest you to separate the find-costumer function and the make-deal function.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have re-worked the setup trying to emphasize separate procedures and here's what I have:                     `to check-for-competitors
   set competitors vehicles in-radius 1
   ifelse count competitors > 1
       [determine-highest-rated]
       [ask competitors [set color red]]
end
to determine-highest-rated
  set highest-rated competitors with-max [rating]
  ifelse count highest-rated > 1
  [break-tie]
  [ask highest-rated [set color orange]]
end
to break-tie
  set tie-breaker highest-rated with-max [who]
  ask tie-breaker [set color brown]
end`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. It's basically 3 procedures. In the first I'm asking the customer to identify any vehicle in-radius 1 (and consequently set their "competitors" variable to those vehicles). If there is more than one competitor, it will run determine-highest-rated and set its highest-rated variable to the highest rated vehicle(s). If there is more than one vehicle with the highest rating it just selects whichever has the highest who number between the two in the third procedure.

Comment: In the actual simulation, all of the [set color -] commands would actually be [make-deal], but I'm just using the colors to observe if it's working properly. With this set-up, the correct vehicle always is always selected, but sometimes one of the other vehicles sets is color red also (this situation results in a runtime error when the [make-deal] procedure is in the correct place).

Comment: Your problem is, just like i told you before. assume there are 2 vehicle (vehicle a and vehicle b) in radius 1. When you run that code,  assume the code run on `vehicle a` first. Then it will make `vehicle b `color red, since `vehicle b` is its competitor. Then the same happened when the code run on vehicle b, it will change `vehicle a` color red since `vehicle a` is `vehicle's b` competitor

Comment: I guess what I'm still not completely understanding is why the "correct" vehicle always turns the right color, and the incorrect vehicle either remains unchanged or turns red. For example if `[rating] vehicle a` > `[rating] vehicle b`, vehicle a always turns orange like it should. Vehicle b either remains unchanged or turns red.

Comment: And if there are any suggestions on how to approach this task differently (determining  which agent has the higher variable value and asking that agent to carry out another procedure; all within the same time step), any input would help.

Comment: I don't really get your logic in your new code. I think the output is already match with your code.  so, in example if [rating] vehicle a > [rating] vehicle b. vehicle a already turns orange like it should. what about the vehicle b? what color it should change into?

Comment: and for my first answer, you basically don't use my suggestion. the way you separate function is not separating. you just use a different function name for each commands.  and it got different problems .

Comment: Thanks for your responses. In the new code above, I'm only asking 1 vehicle (the highest rated) to turn red. The highest rated always turns red, but sometimes they both turn red. This is where I'm stuck.